# Accessing Calendars from a Personal Account through the Microsoft Graph API Non-Interactively

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am aiming to access my calendar data from my personal Microsoft Account via the Microsoft Graph API. Further, I do not want to authenticate myself interactively to get an access token. Instead, I prefer the non-interactive method outlined in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) article.

Applying the non-interactive method of authentication works fine to gain information about users in my Azure Active Directory using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}`.

**Unfortunately, I am always retrieving the error message `OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound` when calling `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/calendars` to get the list of my personal calendars of the user.**

Is it possible to retrieve the calendar data of a personal Outlook account while employing a non-interactive method of authentication?

Answer (score -1):

No, you can not retrieve the calendar data of a personal Outlook account while employing a non-interactive method of authentication.

Comment: Though after interactive authentication, you can use a refresh token to access the calendar APIs right?

Comment: Hello, Is it always impossible ? 
I would use GraphAPI to upload file to my personal Office365 one drive, but just giving access to my ASP.NET Core api

Thanks

Comment: It is possible. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971906/how-to-obtain-refresh-token-in-microsoft-authorization-code-flow-java-sdk

Make use of refresh token to obtain an access token and then make calls to personal microsoft account